# Proof of an inequality: is it correct?

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, tangent-line-method

> Let $x_{1},\cdots, x_{n}>-1$ be real numbers such that
>   $\sum{x_{i}}=n$. Prove that: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{x_{i}+1}}\geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{x_{i}}{x_{i}^{2}+1}}$$

**My proof:** By AM-HM and $\sum{x_{i}}=n$, LHS $\geq \frac{n^{2}}{n+n\times 1}=\frac{n}{2}$

On the other hand, by using AM-GM in the denominator, RHS $\leq \sum{\frac{x_{i}}{2x_{i}}}=\frac{n}{2} \rightarrow$ LHS $\geq$ RHS, with equality iff for all $i$, $x_{i}=1$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it’s correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is right.

Now, your inequality follows from the following C-S.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(1+x_i)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+x_i}\geq n^2.$$

Also, we can use the TL method:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{1+x_i}-\frac{1}{1+x_i^2}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1-x_i}{(1+x_i)(1+x_i^2)}=$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1-x_i}{(1+x_i)(1+x_i^2)}+\frac{1}{4}(x_i-1)\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x_i-1)^2(x_i^2+2x_i+3)}{4(1+x_i)(1+x_i^2)}\geq0.$$

Comment: I was at that first step but I can't go further! Sorry for the (maybe) stupid question, but what is TL method?

Comment: Because $\sum (x_i-1)=0$?

Comment: @gimusi Yes, of course! TL  it's the Tangent Line method. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/tangent-line-method/info

Comment: What was wrong with the second step?

Comment: @DmitriAlexandrovich You just did not make the second step.See please better your own post.

Comment: In fact I did! On the other hand, by using AM-GM in the denominator, RHS $\leq \sum{\frac{x_{i}}{2x_{i}}}=\frac{n}{2} \rightarrow$ LHS $\geq$ RHS, with equality iff for all $i$, $x_{i}=1$.

Comment: @DmitriAlexandrovich You did not prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+x_i}\geq\frac{n}{2}.$ You checked the equality case only.

Comment: Please see the post again, because I have demonstrated my entire solution after the problem (yellow part)! I have just used LHS and RHS for Left Hand Side and ...

Comment: I’ve used AM-HM, which is exactly the same as your Cauchy.

Comment: Yes, of course. Now, I see this point. Id est, your solution is right!

Comment: So, I guess that it’s correct! Thank you.